# Using Jquery variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jQuery selector in an AJAX request call , so according to the value returned by request , I select the required div using :eq() selector, but the problem is that I am stuck with some undefined stuffs

Here is what I wish to do

```
$('.win7red:eq(9)').parent.children('span:eq(1)').children('div:first').css("opacity", "1");
```

Here the value in first eq selector has to be variable as per the request

I obtained the value in a javascript variable called req and then I used this, but it shows ERROR

```
$('.win7red:eq(req)').parent.children('span:eq(1)').children('div:first').css("opacity", "1");
```

I even tried this, but none of them worked

```
$var = $('.win7red');
$var1 = $var:eq(req); 
$var1.parent.children('span:eq(1)').children('div:first').css("opacity", "1");
```

Please help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `parent()` as a **function** instead of a **property**.

So, `$('.win7red:eq(9)').parent`**`( )`** ...

Using `.parent` without parentheses can only be used at DOM objects, such as `$("body").get(0).parentNode` (=`$("body").parent()`).

Comment: Ohh... typing mistake.. While writing code I mistakely wrote parent and never even cared....Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It’s actually ``parentNode`` and not ``parent`` when traversing DOM nodes.